# Conditional Django Query

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using this query for search. I want to search list according to `status`, `start_date` and `end_date`

`status` can be Active, Inactive, or AllStatus.

`start_date` can be date or None(can be empty)

`end_date` can be date or None(can be empty)

```
status = form.cleaned_data['status']
start_date = form.cleaned_data['start_date']
end_date = form.cleaned_data['end_date']
```

I made this below query but it is giving me error - `Cannot use None as a query value`.

Can any tell me whats the problem and how should i query using `status`, `start_date` and `end_date` with sometimes value as `None`

```
Jobs.objects.filter(
    Q(job_company=self.request.user.userprofile.user_company) |
    Q(job_created_on__range=[start_date, end_date]) |
    Q(job_created_on__gt=start_date) |
    Q(job_created_on__lt=end_date) |
    Q(job_status=status)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the lookup dynamically:

```
status = form.cleaned_data['status']
start_date = form.cleaned_data['start_date']
end_date = form.cleaned_data['end_date']
company = self.request.user.userprofile.user_company

lookups = (Q(job_company=company) |  Q(job_status=status) 

if start_date:
    lookups = lookups | Q(job_created_on__gt=start_date)
if end_date:
    lookups = lookups | Q(job_created_on__lt=end_date)

Jobs.objects.filter(lookups)
```

The `job_created_on__range` lookup is unnecessary.

Also, check if you really want `job_created_on__gt/__lt` or `job_created_on__gte/__lte`.

Comment: Sir it is giving me error `received a naive datetime (2019-01-12 00:00:00) while time zone support is active RuntimeWarning` and even Query is not working

Comment: That is most likely an issue with your form and probably best answered in a separate question. Also, no need to call me sir, we are all friends here :)

Comment: Because your datetime expects tzinfo (Time Zone Information) do this. `from django.utils.timezone import make_aware` and `make_aware(start_date)` `make_aware(end_date)`  @HuzaifSayyed

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari `start/end_date` are actually `date` object, see this question & answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237576/runtimewarning-for-datefield-in-django/54238093#54238093